# Entity Framework M2M issue adding foreign key to lookup table

Tags: .net, entity-framework, foreign-keys, duplicates

I have a data model that looks roughly like this:

thingy --< ports >--< technologies

In other words, I have a collection of thingys, which have one or more "ports", each port having one or more technologies. The technologies table is a lookup table, which I use to populate a drop down on the front end that the user can use to assign technologies to ports.

Problem is in my save code for new thingys and ports only. I got update working fine. To add the first thingy, I do the following:

```
dbcontext.entry(thingy).State  = EntityState.Added;
```

This puts the thingy and the object graph associated with it in the context (ie all children objects), all in the "added" state.

This seems to work, but what it actually does is insert duplicate technologies in my technology table. I have ID set on all of my technologies and foreign keys/relationships/etc all look fine.

When I try to do sneaky things like iterate over all of the technologies and change their state to EntityState.Unchanged, I get the following error:

> "Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'Technology' have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration."

Similarly, using find reports the same problem:

```
dbcontext.Technologies.Find(tech.TechnologyID);
```

> "Multiple entities were found in the Added state that match the given
>   primary key values."

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue so that EF properly builds the mapping to the EXISTING technology object instead of adding a new one every time?

Comment: When the root graph is on the added state, all detached graphs underneath it will be marked as added state too, the solution should be attaching them first. I know you mentioned about changing the state to unchanged, but probably you did the wrong way, you need to give more complete code, not only two lines of code that's not reproduceable, otherwise we can't help you, see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)